# Browse a webpage's tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to browse all the links (of a webpage) that contain a specific attribute (e.g all the "a" tags that has the attribute "title".
How can i do this ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: What does "browse all the links" mean?

Comment: @dgabriel: did I miss the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),//Or also document.links
withTitle = [];
for(varn=0;n<links.length;n++)
    if(links[n].getAttribute('title'))
        withTitle.push(links[n]);
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var withTitle = $('a[title]');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the nodes list that is a default property of the document object `document.links`, you can iterate that, like so:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++)
{
    if (document.links[i].hasOwnProperty('title'))
    {
        linksWithTitle.push(document.links[i]);
    }
}
```

or any variaton on this theme

**Edit**

I did some digging, perhaps an alternative approach would be using a treewalker:

```
function byTitle(node)
{
    if (node.hasOwnProperty('title'))
    {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
}

function getElementsWithTitle(root)
{
    root = root || document.links;
    var treeWalker,result;
    treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,byTitle,false);
    result = [treeWalker.currentNode];
    while(treeWalker.nextNode())
    {
        result.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
    }
    return result;
}
```

There's a lot more to treeWalkers and NodeFilters/NodeLists than this, but [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/treewalker.shtml) is a nice introduction to the whole concept.

Lastly, if you don't care about IE compatibility: `document.querySelectorAll('a[title]');` will do the trick

Comment: ok i got that , but why would we use this property anyway we can have the list directly why involving  a "document" property?

Comment: what do you mean: 'we can have the list directly' - if you're referring to the jQuery selector: it basically executes similar code to this behind the screens. The difference is, using pure JS is faster, and doesn't require an extensive lib being loaded. the `document.links` is a nodes list, so you can use the `namedItem()` method on it, too... which might prove usefull (`$('#someId')` is slower than `document.links.namedItem('someId')` for example).